# What is the difference between Reissner-Nordstrom (RN) black hole and dyonic black hole?

Tags: black-holes, terminology, ads-cft, magnetic-monopoles, reissner-nordstrom-metric

*A [RN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reissner%E2%80%93Nordstr%C3%B6m_metric) black hole is a black hole with electric charge, and a [dyonic black hole](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=dyonic+black+hole) with both electric charge and magnetic charge.*

**My Questions**:

1. Is the above statement correct?
2. Is the charges the unique difference between them?
3. If considering the AdS spacetime as background, would the two kinds of black holes realize different holography?